# Get records whose count matches max(count) for a category

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

Given the following rows of course,section,grade,count of grades within course section:

```
course  SECTION  grade  gradeCount
-----------------------------------
1301    001      C      3
1301    001      C+     3
1301    001      C-     4
1301    001      D      5
1301    001      D+     3
1301    001      D-     2
1301    001      F      18
1301    002      A-     1
1301    002      B      1
1301    002      B-     3
1301    002      C      2
```

I want to get a list of course/sections with the greatest number of each grade.

For example:

```
Grade|Course|Section|Count
A | 1301| 023 | 75     // 1301-023 had the most A's, 75 of them
B | 1301| 033 | 65     // 1301-033 had the most B's, 65 of them
```

Ties should appear in the list.

Comment: Your input does not in any way match your output.

Comment: Are you treating all grades as the same, like A- and A+ all are A's.

Comment: Dammit all. I work FOR A COLLEGE ON ITS GRADING SYSTEM!! It's not @#$# homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the gradeCount is already the total of the grades for each unique course, section and grade.

First find the highest count for each grade

```
SELECT
    grade,
    Max(gradeCount) as MaxGradeCount
FROM
    table
```

Then find which lines in the original table have the max grade

```
SELECT
    course,
    section,
    grade,
    gradeCount
FROM
    table

        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
        grade,
        Max(gradeCount) as MaxGradeCount
    FROM
        table
    ) MaxGrades
        ON  table.grade = MaxGrades.grade
            AND table.gradeCount = MaxGrades.MaxGradeCount
ORDER BY 
    table.grade
```

A simple inner join and no CTEs in sight ;-)

Comment: You're using `MaxGradeCount` as a column alias.  `MaxGradeCount.grade` will return a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming at least SQL Server 2005 for the [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx):

```
declare @Test table (
    course char(4),
    section char(3),
    grade char(2),
    gradeCount int
)

insert into @Test
    values ('1301','001','A',100),
           ('1301','002','A',20),
           ('1301','001','B',10),
           ('1301','002','B',50),
           ('1301','003','B',50)

;with cteMaxGradeCount as (
    select grade, max(gradeCount) as MaxGradeCount
        from @Test
        group by grade
)
select t.course, t.SECTION, t.grade, t.gradeCount
    from cteMaxGradeCount c
        inner join @Test t
            on c.grade = t.grade
                and c.MaxGradeCount = t.gradeCount
    order by t.grade
```

Comment: Returns all rows unmodified.  You'd have to group on course and section in addition to grade.

Comment: @Andomar: Not in my simple test. I'll edit the answer with my test data.

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli: Add `('1301','003','A',100)` to your test data.  It will now show both `grade A count 100` and `grade B count 50` for course 1301 section 003.

Comment: @Andomar: The way I interpret the question, that would be valid. It's certainly possible that one class/section would have the maximum of more than one letter grade.

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli: In the example I gave, grade B has a count of 50, and grade A a count of 100. It should not return grade B.  -1 for obviously incorrect answer.

Comment: @Andomar: I'm trying but I'm still not following you. 100 is the maximum number of A's given. 50 is the maximum number of B's given. So, any course/section with 100 A's should be returned and any course/section with 50 B's should be returned.

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli: Riight so it's per grade not per course/section.  I'll remove the downvote...

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the sum per one-letter-grade in a common table expression (CTE).  Then, you can use `not exists` to filter out only the grades with the highest count:

```
; with s as 
    (
    select  course
    ,       section
    ,       left(grade,1) as Grade
    ,       sum(gradeCount) sumGradeCount
    from    YourTable yt1
    group by
            course
    ,       section
    ,       left(grade,1)
    )
select  *
from    s s1
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    s s2
        where   s1.course = s2.course
                and s1.section = s2.section
                and s1.sumGradeCount < s2.SumGradeCount
        )
```

Comment: @Caveatrob: Fixed by altering the `where` clause in the subquery, should work now

Answer (score -3):

You can make use of GroupBy combined with aggregate functions - max(), count().

--Cheers

Comment: This is so basic as to be completely unhelpful.